# How to set a default due date and time for new Reminders?

Tags: reminders

I rely on to-do apps to keep my work and personal life in order. If it needs to be done, I add it immediately to a list, and expect a reminder at the right time.

After using the Reminders app on Mac and iPhone for a long time, I realized there really, really needs to be a default reminder time, e.g. "in two hours".

***Is there a way to set a default due date and time for new Reminders?***

PS: Currently I use TickTick, it's pretty good, syncs with Mac and iPhone (and web and more) and does habit tracking, among other nice things. Its only flaw is the only so-so Siri integration.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to set a default date or time for a reminder.

The only option it provides is to set a default time for 'all day' reminders, but that's it.

Reminders is still pretty basic, even with the latest updates.  I'd think you will need to continue using, and looking for, 3rd-party applications.